# Как правильней всего реализовать этот элемент?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, frontend

[image: пример]

Концепт на изображении.
Без наведения виден только круг. При наведении появляются 4 зоны (с цифрами). При наведении на зону, как на картинке, она немного увеличивается.

Использовать можно HTML, CSS и JavaScript в крайнем случае.

Answer (score 7):

На чистом CSS

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.curcle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.curcle .item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
  border-color: #333;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0;
}

.curcle .item:nth-child(1) {
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100%;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}

.curcle .item:nth-child(2) {
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.curcle .item:nth-child(4) {
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.curcle .item:nth-child(3) {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-left-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  transform-origin: right top;
}

.curcle .invert {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.curcle:hover {
  border: 0;
}

.curcle:hover .item {
  opacity: 1;
}

.curcle .item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.25);
}

/* Не относится к коду */
#anim {display: none;}
label {cursor: pointer;}
#anim:checked ~ label {color: green;}
#anim:checked ~ .curcle .item {
  transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="anim">
<label for="anim">Включить плавность при наведение</label>

<div class="curcle">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="invert">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="invert">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="invert">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="invert">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```